# The method returns a superclass object with subclass fields

Tags: java, spring

I have a `Movie` object in the program

```
public class Movie extends BaseDTO {
      ...
      public static class Builder<T extends Builder> extends BaseDTO.Builder<T> { ... }
}
```

from this object inherits `UserMovie`

```
public class UserMovie extends Movie {
     //there are two additional fields
     private final Integer yourRating;
     private final boolean favorited;

     public static class Builder extends Movie.Builder<Builder> { ... }
}
```

In some part of the code I want to convert entities to DTO objects. I have two methods. One to convert entities into `Movie` DTO

```
static Movie toMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    return ((Movie.Builder) initMovieDto(movieEntity)).build();
}
```

the second method to convert to `UserMovie` DTO

```
static UserMovie toUserMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity, final UserEntity userEntity) {
    final UserMovie.Builder builder = initMovieDto(movieEntity);

   builder.withYourRating(...);
   builder.withFavorited(userEntity.getFavoritesMovies().contains(movieEntity));

    return builder.build();
}
```

both methods use a common method to initialize data in the Builder pattern

```
private static UserMovie.Builder initMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    final UserMovie.Builder builder = new UserMovie.Builder(
            movieEntity.getTitle(),
            movieEntity.getType()
    )
            .withId(movieEntity.getId().toString());

    builder.withRating(...);
    ...
    return builder;
}
```

It turns out that the `toMovieDto` method returns the `UserMovie` object. Why is this happening? I do not want private fields for `UserMovie` to be returned in `Movie`. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried that someone might cast the `Movie` returned from `toMovieDto` into `UserMovie`? I wouldn't worry about that much - this requires explicit casting. (Compare it how methods in e.g. `Collections` class are defined, or in any `Collection` implementations).

If you are really worried about security (and only in this case) you need to create another `initMovieDto` method, that user builder from Movie and not from `UserMovie` like currently.

So something like this:

```
private static Movie.Builder initMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    final Movie.Builder builder = new Movie.Builder(
            movieEntity.getTitle(),
            movieEntity.getType()
    )
            .withId(movieEntity.getId().toString());
    ...
    return builder;
}

static Movie toMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    return ((Movie.Builder) initMovieDto(movieEntity)).build();
}
```

and separate for UserMovie:

```
private static UserMovie.Builder initUserMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity) {
    final UserMovie.Builder builder = new UserMovie.Builder(
            movieEntity.getTitle(),
            movieEntity.getType()
    )
            .withId(movieEntity.getId().toString());

    builder.withRating(...);
    ...
    return builder;
}

static UserMovie toUserMovieDto(final MovieEntity movieEntity, final UserEntity userEntity) {
    final UserMovie.Builder builder = initUserMovieDto(movieEntity);

   builder.withYourRating(...);
   builder.withFavorited(userEntity.getFavoritesMovies().contains(movieEntity));

    return builder.build();
}
```

This way you will return not only the interface like you want but also concrete class of the same type as the return type in `toMovieDto` and `toUserMovieDto`.

Another option would be to define UserMovie builder such that one of it's options would accept a Movie builder.